# BricsCAD V20 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, bricscad

I used BricsCAD V20 CAD application quite regularly on Ubuntu 20.04. I recently upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04.1 LTS. Now, BricsCAD has a display issue - the main drawing viewport doesn't render. This means that while the drawing is open (there is evidence that the file is actually open) the viewport just turns blank - meaning that there's no work that I can actually do on the drawing. To repeat - the application is actually running, all functions are available - but the computer doesn't display the main drawing area.

I tried a few things:

1. Checked launching from terminal and then boiled it down to a gnome issue. I think the (mix of) gnome that 22.04 uses is not fully compatible with BC20. BUT, an 'ldd' on the BC20 executable doesn't show any dependency error. Has anyone any experience like this or managed to solve it?
2. Downloaded a trial of BC V22 and tried it. It works as expected. But I obviously don't know what the diff between bricscad 20 and bricscad 22 render engine is...

So, I wanted to know (before I spend money on this proprietary **ite) if anyone has experienced this, managed to work it out, etc. For example, has anyone tried a previous version of gnome on U22.04, or maybe a different DE?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 defaults to Wayland, and 20.04 defaulted to Xorg. Are you running Wayland or Xorg? If Wayland, switch to xorg and see if that helps.

Comment: It seems wayland. I'll do what you @esther suggested and update

Answer (score 0):

@esther - your suggestion worked - switching to xorg did the trick. It also solved some other buggy things like a flickering top bar and dock, and removed indicator-stickynotes from the window and workspace switcher (see [Don't want stickynotes on the dock, app or workspace switcher, only on desktop](https://askubuntu.com/q/1427199/1628465)).

I'm going to mark this question as solved as the immediate issue was in fact resolved. But it doesn't take away from the underlying issue with wayland. I guess in some future update. I will retry wayland in a few days/a week or so and file a bug report if the issue persists.