# Don't want stickynotes on the dock, app or workspace switcher, only on desktop

Tags: 22.04, stickynotes

Title describes it. Since upgrade to 22.04 the indicator turns up on the dock, the window switcher, the workspace switcher. Pretty annoying. Anyone facing same issue and found a way to get indicator-stickynotes to be just on the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround suggested by user https://askubuntu.com/users/1083397/esther sorts this out - the issue seems to be with wayland so switching to xorg worked in removing this issue and a couple of others. See here [BricsCAD V20 on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1427194/1628465)

Thanks Esther.